# Prevent MySQL/Node.js webapp from automatically repeating queries to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm working on a MERN webapp (using MySQL instead of MongoDB) and we are having an issue where at some point after querying to add an entry, the backend is somehow re-querying the last query. In the meantime, between the original entry and the duplicate one, the backend runs continuously to keep the frontend displaying up-to-date data.

I've read on old threads that MySQL for Node may have some issues with memory leaking and thus running sleep queries. I don't believe this is a frontend issue, and the backend isn't running the queries as if they were called from the function that handles the frontend button click (to submit).

I'm a noob to full-stack JS, so I don't really know where to look for an answer to this issue. I'm not sure if we should band-aid the solution and just make sure a query isn't sent without the submit button being clicked within a 1 second time span.

EDIT: Here's code for the query to add the entry (data for a music album).

```
db.query(insertAlbumQuery, insertAlbumValues, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 Album added.");
    });
```

We don't close the connection to the db after querying, one connection runs for the duration of the app's execution.

Here's the code for the db connection:

```
let mysql = require("mysql");
var db;

function connectDB() {
  if (!db) {
    db = connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "******",
      user: "******",
      password: "******",
      database: "******"
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error("error: " + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Connected to the MySQL server.");
      }
    });
  }
  return db;
}

module.exports = connectDB();
```

From the main, backend app.js file we have the router post

```
router.post("/addAlbum", (req, res) => {
    const {
        Album_title,
        Artist,
        Release_date,
        Category,
        Description,
        Rotation

    } = req.body;

    album.add(Album_title, Artist, Release_date, Category, Description, Rotation, null);
});
```

From the front end we post with

```
 addAlbum = currentState => {
    this.setState({ Rotation: +this.state.Rotation });
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/addAlbum", this.state);
  };
```

Not sure if this is enough background on the app, but I can add more snippets if needed.

Comment: I guess not much can be done unless  there  is some code provided

Comment: To make sure it is not front end related, setup a onClick JavaScript to disable the submit button.  This way it can only be clicked once.  If it still happens == backend.

Comment: Does this happen consistently with every new entry in the db, or it happens intermittently?

Comment: oh and please post some code snippets.

Comment: Since you are using Express. Post use the code for the `controller` registered at the `route` for the `api` that you are currently building. This should be the code where you execute the query to `mysql` using javascript.

Comment: Edited and added the code for the route, along with the code for the db connection itself.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the insert query is executing multiple times when the `addAlbum(currentState)` is triggered from the frontend OR does the insert query execute, and then the previous query (maybe a `fetchAllAlbums` or whatever was last queried) fire again?

Comment: The insert query only executes once from the initial frontend call, but after `fetchAllAlbums` is queried a few times it executes a second time. I have checked that the button is not the source of the call to query. It's as if the query has been put in a queue to execute but, once it is executed, it doesn't leave the queue, it just keeps being executed along with the queries to `fetchAllAlbums`. I'm not sure if there is something that we should have implemented that "clears" the `addAlbum` query after it is executed.

Comment: Whoops, I see that you're using `mysql`...Original Post: 'which `mysql` client are you using? `mysql`, `mysql2`, or something else'

Comment: Is the data of the second insert the same or is it missing a value for `Rotation`

Comment: Exactly the same. It actually fails because the database returns a duplicate error.

Comment: Is `addAlbum(currentState)` a redux `thunk`? `this.setState({ Rotation: +this.state.Rotation });` says that you are re-assigning the current value of `this.state.Rotation` to `this.state.Rotation`, but also triggering React to reload the virtual DOM, re-rendering your component. This doesn't make sense to do and is causing some performance issues. Also, how is `addAlbum(currrentState)` being called. If it is called within the any code that is involved with render, a request will be sent to the API every time the component renders

Comment: Have you checked your Network requests in the Developer tools in your browser to see if multiple requests are being made?

Comment: Post the code where you are calling `addAlbum(currentSate)` so we can see what's going on. I would recommend just posting your entire component.

Comment: The problem has stopped occurring for the time being, but I will update tomorrow when I can say for sure.